# Kann man auf *der* ganzen Linie enttäuschen?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definite-article

Die ARD schreibt in einem Sportbeitrag "enttäuschten auf der ganzen Linie". Die Linie wurde mit einem bestimmten Artikel versehen. Ich kenne es eigentlich nur unbestimmt, also: "enttäuschten auf ganzer Linie". Ist das nur Gewohnheit oder hat es einen speziellen Grund, warum die Unbestimmtheit besser wäre? Ist die Artikelweglassung überhaupt unbestimmt, kann man das so sagen?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ja, kann man. Siehe Beispiele des Dudens:

> **Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter**
>
> auf der ganzen/auf ganzer Linie (völlig; in jeder Beziehung: auf der ganzen Linie versagen; die Mannschaft enttäuschte auf ganzer Linie)
>
> in erster/zweiter Linie (an erster/zweiter, weniger wichtiger Stelle: in erster Linie geht es darum, dass wir gewinnen; das interessiert uns erst in zweiter Linie)

Die Frage nach dem "Warum?" läßt sich bei einer solchen Redensart natürlich schwer beantworten. Man geht davon aus, dass die Redensart aus der Militärsprache entlehnt wurde wo die Linie die *Frontlinie* darstellt, in der sich die Truppen gegenüberstehen. Und da "ganze Linie" eben "alle" bedeutet (also gar keine bestimmte Linie gemeint ist), ist es vollkommen unerheblich, ob der bestimmte oder gar kein Artikel verwendet wird.

Answer (score 2):

"Auf ganzer Linie" meint ja üblicherweise Linie im übertragenen Sinn. Da es aber im Fußball ja durchaus reale Linie gibt (Torlinie, Torauslinie, Seitenlinie etc.), ist es denkbar, dass das "auf **der** ganzen Linie" als Wortspiel gemeint war und der Autor deshalb die unübliche, aber eben doch zulässige Formulierung gewählt hat.

Comment: Es zwar vorstellbar, aber einigermassen unwahrscheinlich, dass da 11 Leute auf der Torauslinie rumgestanden und daselbst versagt haben.

Answer (score 1):

Wie tofro schreibt, es geht beides. Der Unterschied kommt wie bei so vielem aus den deutschen Dialekten. Im Süden ist es Gang und Gebe überall Pronomen davorzusetzen, besonders auffällig bei Namen, z.B. "Ich gebe dem Julian den Brief"
Ich denke dass im 'hochdeutsch' "auf ganzer Linie" eher korrekt wäre, jedoch gibt es speziell bei Redewendungen sehr viele Einflüsse die sich einbürgern, folglich findet sich auch beides im Duden.

Comment: Du meinst einen Artikel vor dem Namen, bist du sicher, daß das auch in weiteren unbestimmten Zusammenhängen der Fall ist?

Comment: Du hast Recht, "mit großer Begeisterung" und "unter widrigen Bedingungen" werden nicht abgeändert. Im ursprünglichen schwäbischen ist dieser Satzbau aber generell sehr selten gesehen. Schwäbische Grammatik ist oft sehr simple, oben genannte konstrukte würden als "sich freuen", "a oozklomp" formen